# Problems opening port 465 for smtp on centos

Tags: centos, iptables, smtp

I'm using [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) to send off purchase confirmations using a google apps address/smtp. The whole thing was working great on the development box, but now that it's live, it seems that the port I'm using (465) is blocked.

So I edit iptables with:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -dport 465 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -sport 465 -j ACCEPT
```

My understanding is that this allows inbound & outbound connections on 465 (correct me if I'm wrong). After restarting iptables:

```
iptables -nL  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target   prot   opt   source      destination
ACCEPT   tcp    --    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:465
ACCEPT   tcp    --    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   tcp spt:465
```

However I still receive "Failed to connect to server: Permission denied" as debug from phpMailer. From what I've read, this usually indicates that the port is closed, & [evidently](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) that is the case.

Any hints on how to debug this further? Any help would be much appreciated.

In case it helps, here's the php:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();        
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //!DEV
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = $emailAddress;
$mail->Password = $emailPassword;
$mail->SetFrom($emailAddress, 'PURCHASE ORDER');
$mail->AddAddress($customerEmail);
$mail->AddAddress($salesEmail); 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;        
$mail->Send() or die('Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
```

*Edit: The mailer works flawlessly on the development server - any advice on ways to compare what may be different? Same OS, same php... I'm stumped!

Comment: Your `INPUT` policy is `ACCEPT` so these rules are unnecessary.  The packets would be passed anyway.  I'm willing to bet that your `OUTPUT` chain is empty and has an `ACCEPT` policy too.

Answer (score 6):

You've told your server to accept **incoming** connections on port 465, but then you're also telling it to connect to smtp.gmail.com which is an **outbound** connection.

You will need to open the same ports, but on the OUTPUT chain instead of the INPUT one:

`-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT`

To edit from the terminal the command would be:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: You won't need the `-sport` rule.  The source port will be random and high.

Comment: Ladadadada - you're right, I shouldn't try copy-pasting until I've had my second cup of coffee... I removed the sport line.

Answer (score 3):

A firewall problem *should* cause either "The connection was reset" or "The connection timed out" error messages.  PHPMailer *might* be giving you a "Permission denied" error message instead of one of those two but that would be a *bad error message*.  (It wouldn't be the first time I have seen bad error messages.)

If the error message "Failed to connect to server: Permission denied" is helpful, it suggests that you have `safe_mode` on or you have disallowed opening sockets in your `php.ini`.

This could also be caused by SELinux.  I'm not familiar enough with it to tell you what to do to determine if this is the case or to fix it.

Comment: Double checked safe_mode = Off, sockets = enabled.